# matplotlib plot in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to connect every 10th point?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #points = np.fromfile('test_acc_history.txt')
    points = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    plt.figure(100)
    plt.plot(points)

    plt.show()
```

The output results in:

[image]

BUT, I wanna have a result which should look like a curve:

[image]

Comment: Your second code is not even valid python. Please create a  [mcve] of the issue. Also explain what is wrong with the output more clearly. What *is*  the blue data and the red data and why would you expect them to be equal?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest now it should be

Comment: No it is not. If you're having a problem, you need to make it reproducible for others. If [mcve] is not understandable to you, maybe [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) will help.

Comment: now it should be as it should be...

Comment: Copy your code, try to run it: It will not work. The explanation of the problem is also still the same: not clear. I'm giving up on this now.

Comment: I updated the whole post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to plot every `n`th point, you can slice the array, `points[::n]`. To then make sure to have them plotted at the correct position, you also need to supply a list of x values, which is every `n`th point from the integer number range.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

plt.plot(points)
plt.plot(range(len(points))[::10],points[::10] )

plt.show()
```

[image]